# Possible strict violation one place but not another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I know there are a few `possible strict violation` questions on here, but I haven't been able to come to a result based on them. I am trying to use `var vm = this` in a controller in one class and it's throwing this error, but I have done the same thing in other controllers more than once with no `possible strict violation` errors.

So here is the first js file. it's an angular directive with the controller in the same file. The error is coming from the `var vm = this` in the controller below.

```
angular.module('app.monitor').directive('scModelLegacyViewer',
      scModelLegacyViewer);

  function scModelLegacyViewer() {

    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      templateUrl : 'app/monitor/monitor.html',
      scope : {
        config : '=',
        register : '&?',
        data : '=?',
        allowEditingSwitch : '=?'
      },
      controller: scModelLegacyViewerController,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
  }

  scModelLegacyViewerController.$inject = [ '$q', '$scope', '$timeout', 'config',
                                            'logger', 'ProjectService', 'ModelService', 'InstanceService',
                                            'BayesianService'];

  function scModelLegacyViewerController($q, $scope, $timeout,
      config, logger, ProjectService,
      ModelService, InstanceService, BayesianService) {
      var vm = this;  // HERE IS THE ERROR LINE
      vm.modelInstanceChannel = 'MODEL_INSTANCE';
      vm.saveAll = saveAll;
      ...
```

Another file where this works perfectly is this for example, which throws no errors:

```
 angular
    .module('app.model')
    .controller('ModelController', ModelController);

  //scInitialConfig added in model.route.js
  ModelController.$inject = ['$document', '$interval', '$scope', '$stateParams', 'logger',
      'modelService', 'scInitialConfig'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function ModelController($document, $interval, $scope, $stateParams, logger,
      modelService, scInitialConfig) {
    var vm = this;
    var data = null;
    vm.instance = 'default';
    vm.title = 'Model Viewer';
    ...
```

The only difference that I can come up with is that @ the top of the first file I am declaring the `directive` but in the 2nd file it is just the `controller`. Unfortunately I'm not an angular expert, so I don't know if that is an issue, but just thinking this might be where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename function scModelLegacyViewerController to ScModelLegacyViewerController. JsHint allows assigning this to a variable only if the name starts with a capital letter.
So it's going to be

```
angular.module('app.monitor').directive('scModelLegacyViewer',
      scModelLegacyViewer);

  function scModelLegacyViewer() {

    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      templateUrl : 'app/monitor/monitor.html',
      scope : {
        config : '=',
        register : '&?',
        data : '=?',
        allowEditingSwitch : '=?'
      },
      controller: ScModelLegacyViewerController,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
  }

  function  ScModelLegacyViewerController() {/*code*/}
```

Comment: just to add, jsHint assumes a function starting with a capital is a constructor function where using `this` is appropriate while using `this` in a non constructor function is a little suspect

Comment: That's weird. I had tried this before you made the response based off of another SO question and didn't get a positive result. I got back into work this morning (just now) and started a new command prompt, rand `gulp vet` and it worked. So yeah, haha guess this was it. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use **this** to assign properties?

I mean
`this.foo = 'bar';`

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but I'm looking for the correct way to do this and your response looks more framed as a suggestion/question. Per the Angular Style Guide and the implementation ([Generator-Hottowel by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel/blob/master/app/templates/src/client/app/dashboard/dashboard.controller.js)) `var vm = this;` is more appropriate. I'm trying to resolve the issue in terms of my implementation.